# Before Login Action

Tags: wordpress

I am working on an plugin for wordpress that will check against an external database to see if the user is a member of that site.  If they are, and they don't have a wp login, then the plugin will need to create a login for them.  I have everything working (at least in isolation/unit testing), but what I cannot figure out is how to hook into the login process.

Basically what I need to happen is when the login form is submitted, I first need wp to call my function in my plugin.  My plugin will then either create a new user (if needed), then I will let wp continue with login.

How can I do that?  Is there an action that I am missing?

Comment: Have you asked this on the Wordpress help forums?

Comment: Yes, I have done that. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/313267?replies=1

Comment: I've seen that you had a working solution in the link you provided. You can answer your own question here so other people would benefit from your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was to hook into the action "wp_login_failed".  So if the member was not a member of the wp site, then my method was called, which then called the external site.  If a member was found, a member was created (using "wp_insert_user()"), and then manually logged in.

If you do this, make sure that you use "wp_redirect()" to send them where you want them to go, otherwise the system will present them with an error screen as wp_login has registered a bunch of errors.  (Unless you know how to clear the errors).

Comment: How you logged in the user manually? Is it possible to login any user without password?